# Mac Big Sur: Make unread mails on Mail app only for mail after a specific date

Tags: macos

I linked my Gmail accounts to the Mail app in MacOS.

Unfortunately I got a huge catalog of Emails I didn't bother to open, and it looks [like this](https://i.gyazo.com/be84698aa6a53b61c9566359259b6369.png) in the toolbar.

I could mark all the unread mail as read, but then that may hurt me later on when I want to check whether I actually read an Email or not.

So this gave me an idea - is it possible to customize the number of unread Emails on the app icon only for Emails after a particular date, such as May 1, 2021?  This way I can leave all the unread mails in the past as is, and know how many unread Emails I had from a particular day.